# A decorator that returns multiple functions

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'd like to write a decorator that places multiple functions into the module namespace. Consider the following module:

```py
# my_module.py


from scipy import signal


@desired_decorator(new_size=(8, 16, 32))
def resample(x, new_size):
    return signal.resample(x, new_size)
```

I'd like to now be able to import `resample_8`, `resample_16`, and `resample_32` from `my_module`. I can write the decorator and have it return a list of functions, but how can those functions be made available in the module namespace?

Comment: Does `resample_8,resample_16,resample_32=resample` afterwards count?

Comment: That's now how decorators work. Take a look at [the source code for `anosql`](https://github.com/honza/anosql/blob/23c109f811da6da7fc426414b0c9d7b8b106491e/anosql/core.py#L164), a library that dynamically creates functions from SQL code, for inspiration. Or maybe look at [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: (But why do you need a function named `resample_8()`? How is that any better than `resample(8)`? IMO the latter looks easier to use. There's a good chance this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the fact that you can assign to the global dictionary without using sneaky hacks, this is just almost possible. (grammar nice)

EDIT: K, maybe it's a *lil* bit sneaky. Don't try this at home without a supervising Pythonista. [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau)

EDIT2: It is possible to get the caller's globals by using stack introspection, which avoids the importing problem, but it won't work when invoked in a non-global namespace, or dissipate your confusion in 6 months. [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112)

`globals()` returns a dictionary of the global variables. Assigning to this makes it possible for a user to import these functions

`functools.partial` is a great way to make partial functions. This basically makes a 'half complete' function call. Creating a partial function makes it remember the arguments and keyword arguments and calling that partial function will call the original function with the arguments and keyword arguments. Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Here's the decorator you want, though I would strongly suggest against using this.

```py
from functools import partial

def desired_decorator(**kwargs):
    # make sure there's only one keyword argument
    assert len(kwargs) == 1
    # unpack the single keyword and the values
    keyword, values = (*kwargs.items(),)[0]
    # this is the actual decorator that gets called
    def _make_variants(func):
        for value in values:
            # assign to the globals dictionary
            globals()[
                f"{func.__name__}_{value}"
            ] = partial(func, **{keyword: value})
        # keep the original function available
        return func
    return _make_variants
```

My alternative would be to use what [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) said as creating many functions from a decorator would not be good for maintenance and for clarity.

Here's the code I suggest, but you can use the one above if you want.

```py
from functools import partial

# assign your function things here
resample_8 = partial(resample, new_size=8)
# repeat for other names
```

Comment: This looks good! The only problem I have here is that `globals` gets the symbol table for the module where the decorator is defined, not where it is run, so importing the decorator won't work. Like you and @Chris said, I'll probably steer clear of this.

Comment: Ah, seems like I skipped over the 'importing the decorator' part. That's gonna be a lot harder, but it looks like it won't matter now.

Comment: IMO assigning to the global dictionary in a decorator _is_ a sneaky hack (if it worked in this case).

Comment: You can access the caller's globals with stack inspection, avoiding the import problem, but not avoiding problems like "what if I try to use this decorator in a non-global namespace" or "how much of a maintenance and readability headache is this thing going to be 6 months down the line".

Comment: @user2357112's comment should be added to the answer for future readers.